# simplexml_load_file() giving error: Warning: simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have XML document captured from a link and anytime I use simplexml_load_file(), it gives me an error saying ***Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://kga-dev.mirakl.net/api/shops?:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\wamp\www\merchants\get_merchants.php on line 6***

This is a part of my xml file

```
<body>
<shops>
<shop>...</shop>
<shop>
<approval_delay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<approval_rate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<order_messages_response_delay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<banner xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<billing_info>
<bank_city xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<bank_name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<bank_street xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<zip_code xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<bic xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<iban xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<owner xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</billing_info>
```

And this is my simple php code

```
<?php

    $apiLink = "https://kga-dev.mirakl.net/api/shops?";

    $xml=simplexml_load_file($apiLink);
    print_r($xml);

    //echo $xml->shop_id;

?>
```

Comment: What is the first sign of the read in xml data? Have you tried to get the first sign of the xml data by file_get_contents() and then locate the first sign available. SimpleXML expects a "<" and this is not given. So another sign is the first sign in the content read in. Which one is it? Perhaps it helps to get the content and trim it?

Comment: Just did file_get_contents() and I got this
{"shops":[{"approval_delay":null,"approval_rate":null,"banner":null,"billing_info":{"bank_city":null,"bank_name":null,"bank_street":null,"bic":null,"iban":null,"owner":null,"zip_code":null},"channels":["INIT"],"closed_from":null,"closed_to":null,"contact_informations":

Comment: So as you see, this is not XML. This looks like a REST Response in JSON. Try json_decode() on this content and you 'll have the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is, that the API serves a JSON encoded string instead of an XML string. So the delivered content can not be parsed with SimpleXML. Try to get it with the following example

```
$content = file_get_contents($apiLink);
$data = json_decode($content);
```

In this case $data should be an object or array with all the data the api delivers.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code

```
<approval_rate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

use single quotes

```
<?php
  echo "<order_messages_response_delay xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:nil='true'/>";
?>
```

Comment: I have no access to change that. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You need to change your get_merchants.php form you have written that code above

Comment: You don't understand. The XML is from from an API and I cannot change the document. I'm just trying to load it and get details from it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is the same XML as returned to the script? Note that you are not calling `:1` - I cannot check as it requires authorization, yet in the example given by you there is no error up to line 7 so it would mean that possibly something else is returned as the code below works:

```
<?php
$s = '<body>
    <shops>
        <shop>...</shop>
        <shop>
            <approval_delay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <approval_rate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <order_messages_response_delay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <banner xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </shop>
    </shops>
</body>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($s);
print_r($xml);
```

?>

Is not the authorization the problem your end? I need to authorize to your webservice: you handle that in a different way for your IP or something like that?

Comment: I removed some parts of the xml but that is how it begins. Also I removed some parts of the link so no one can access it as it contains so privileged info.

Comment: I am guessing that your line 6 may be different due to what you have cut - in example a different shop returned first (?) and something before it is not closed properly.

Comment: Line 6 is exactly this line. $xml=simplexml_load_file($apiLink);

Comment: Line 6 of your XML :) - the PHP part is fine. Yet the error can be in previous lines (something not closed).

Comment: All Tags are closed
`
<body>
<shops>
<shop>
<approval_delay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<approval_rate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</shops>
<total_count>35</total_count>
</body>
`